# I have this where i need to create a class and use setter and getters do do various tasks, i just wanted input on what i was doing wrong

Tags: java

this code is supposed to ask the user for name of an ingredient, the number of cups used in the ingredient, and the unit measurement and calculate the total calories for them it involves alot of validation of user input and i have that part down so far but im just lost at this point. the confusing part is the error i get is that this code doe not have a main method

```
package Ingredient;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class V3 {
    
 //Private Fields: Internal Data 
    
    private String nameOfIngredient;
    private String unitMeasurement;
    private float ingredientAmount;             
    private int numberOfCaloriesPerUnit;
    private int numberOfCups;
    private double totalCalories;           

//Operations: Public Methods

    //Mutators and Accessors: Set Values at the this. Index and Return the Value 

    //Set and Return Name of Ingredient 
         public void setNameOfIngredient(String nameOfIngredient) {
            this.nameOfIngredient = nameOfIngredient;
        }
        public String getNameOfIngredient() {
            return nameOfIngredient;
        }
        
        public void setNumberOfCups(int numberOfcups) {
            this.numberOfCups = numberOfCups;
        }
        public int getNumberOfCups() {
            return numberOfCups;
        }
        
        
    
    //Set and Return Unit Measurement
    public void setUnitMeasurement (String unitMeasurement) {
        this.unitMeasurement = unitMeasurement;
    }
    
    public String getUnitMeasurement () {
        return unitMeasurement;
    }
    
    //Set and Return Ingredient Amount
    public void setIngredientAmount(float ingredientAmount) {
        this.ingredientAmount = ingredientAmount;
        }
    
    public float getIngredientAmount() {
        return ingredientAmount;
        }

    //Set and Return Number of Calories per Unit    
    public void setNumberCaloriesPerUnit(int numberCaloriesPerUnit) {
        this.numberOfCaloriesPerUnit = numberCaloriesPerUnit;
        }
    
    public int getNumberCaloriesPerUnit() {
        return numberOfCaloriesPerUnit;
    
    }
    
    //Set and Return Total Calories
    public void setTotalCalories(double totalCalories) {
        this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
        }
    
    public double getTotalCalories() {
        return totalCalories;
        }


    public void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Use this. pointer to initialize fields (as they share the same name as private/global fields)
        this.nameOfIngredient = "";
        this.numberOfCups = 0;
        this.numberOfCaloriesPerUnit = 0;
        this.totalCalories = 0.0;
    
    //Prompt user for name of ingredient
        System.out.println("Please Enter Ingredient Name: ");
        if (scnr.hasNextLine())) {
            nameOfIngredient = scnr.nextLine(); 
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid name (characters only): ");
        }
            
    //Prompt user for unit of measurement
        System.out.println("Please Enter Unit of Measurement for this Ingredient. You have the following options: ");
        System.out.println("Cup(s)");
        System.out.println("Tbsp");
        System.out.println("Tsp");
        System.out.println("Gram(s)");
        
        if (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
            unitMeasurement = scnr.next();
        
            if ((unitMeasurement == "Cup(s)") || (unitMeasurement == "Tbsp") || (unitMeasurement == "Tsp") || (unitMeasurement == "Gram(s)")) {
                System.out.println("You have selected " + unitMeasurement);
            }
            
            else {
                System.out.println("Please enter one of the preceding options.");
            }
            
                else {
            System.out.println("Please enter one of the preceding options.");
            }
                }
        
    //Prompt user for number of units 
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of units of " + nameOfIngredient + " required (between 1 and 100: ");
            
        if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            ingredientAmount = scnr.nextInt();
                
            if ((ingredientAmount >= 1) && (ingredientAmount <= 100)) {
                System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is a valid amount!");   
                    
                        }else {
            System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is not a valid amount.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number of units between 1 and 100: ");
                                }   
                if ((ingredientAmount >= 1) && (ingredientAmount <= 100)) {
                    System.out.println(numberOfCups + " is a valid amount!");   
            }
                else if (ingredientAmount < 1) {
                    System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is less than 1 unit. Sorry, you are out of attempts.");
            }
                else {
                    System.out.println(ingredientAmount + " is greater than 100 units. Sorry, you are out of attempts.");
            }
            
        else {
           System.out.println("Error: That is not a number. Try again.");
        }
                }
    
    //Prompt user for calories per unit
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per unit of " + nameOfIngredient + " (between 1 and 2000): ");
        
        if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            numberOfCaloriesPerUnit = scnr.nextInt();
            
            if ((numberOfCaloriesPerUnit >= 1) && (numberOfCaloriesPerUnit <= 2000)) {
                System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is a valid number of calories!" );
                        
            
            else {
                System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is not a valid number of calories.");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number of calories per unit between 1 and 2000: ");
        
                    if ((numberOfCaloriesPerUnit >= 1) && (numberOfCaloriesPerUnit <= 2000)) {
                        System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is a valid number of calories!");    
                }
                    else if (numberOfCaloriesPerUnit < 1) {
                        System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is less than 1. Sorry, you are out of attempts.");
                }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(numberOfCaloriesPerUnit + " is greater than        2000. Sorry, you are out of attempts.");
                }
                        }
                
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Error: That is not a number. Try again.");
                        }
                        }
                        
                
                
    
        
                //Calculate total calories
                totalCalories = ingredientAmount * numberOfCaloriesPerUnit;
        
                System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + ingredientAmount + "    number of " + unitMeasurement + "'s" + " which contains " + totalCalories + " total            calories.");
        System.out.println("Ingredient has been successfully added.");
                        }
                    
        
                }
            }
```

Comment: It might be useful to ask a specific question. It's harder to answer something that is very general and open-ended. If you're just looking for general code review from a community, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for the resource, i added what was throwing me off apologies

Comment: It sounds like your code doesn't have a main function. But if it doesn't can you check if there is any test code? If not, look into how you can write tests to actually ensure that the code is running properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the static keyword.

As the error you get points out, you don't have the main method properly defined. You are defining your main method as `public void main(String[] args)` which should be defined `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: I had static in there but when it is in there, my pointers do not work and i get the error "non static variable cannot be referenced in a static context, if i have the pointers in the set and get functions onlt then they are not defines in the main

Comment: Then i get the error mypackage.myclass does not have a main method  but i have it in there*  public void main(String[] args) {}

Comment: I suggest you learn some Java basics first, the main function should be static. And use class instance inside main to access your variables.